# Who is the mind behind 'vault boy' drawing style?

Tags: fallout

Every gamer knows fallout and most likely has seen 'vault boy' drawing style

Example would be.

[image]

I tried looking on the net who was inventor of this.

Fallout one artists [Leonard Boyarsky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonard_Boyarsky), [Jason D. Anderson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jason_Anderson_(artist)) and Gary Platner when googled for images do not bring out any vault boy like results.

**Who 'invented' fallout like drawing style?**

Comment: Wasn't this style super common in 1920?

Comment: Asking who is responsible for the artwork in a game is not a speculative question about developer intent.  The people who worked on a game is concrete knowledge that does not require access to the minds of the developers to answer.  This question should be re-opened.

Comment: @JasonBerkan It's concrete knowledge *because we've been told*.  It literally is a developer intent question, which we can only answer because we have the knowledge.  Whether it's been answered or not is irrelevant.

Comment: @MooingDuck I don't know about the 1920's, though it does sort of match old newspaper ads I've seen. I do know for sure this style was alive and well during the era of 1990s MS word clipart. lol

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Vault Boy was originally conceived by [Leonard Boyarsky](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Leonard_Boyarsky) and the first concept art was drawn by [Tramell Ray Isaac](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Tramell_Ray_Isaac).

[image: Original Vault Boy Art]

The design itself is based on Rich Uncle Pennybags, the mascot for the board game Monopoly. Rich Uncle Pennybags was originally drawn by Dan Fox.

Sources:

- http://www.nma-fallout.com/content.php?page=on-vault-boy-and-pip-boy
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Uncle_Pennybags

Comment: Rich Uncle Pennybags was drawn by artist Dan Fox. Source: "Meet Dan Fox," _Association of Game & Puzzle Collectors Quarterly 10_, no. 1 (June 4, 2013).

Comment: @Dan Nice one. Edited that into my answer.